# Unable to plot multi markers using Vue browser script

Tags: google-maps, vue.js, google-maps-markers

It is working fine if i hard code markers lat long where as when it is built using function, it does not plot. In below code, only two markers are coming up where as it should be 3.

I have tried with complete vue browser script, as a static marker objects it is working fine but not with dynamic markers

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root">
    <gmap-map ref="mymap" :center="startLocation" :zoom="14" style="width: 100%; height: 300px">

      <gmap-info-window :options="infoOptions" :position="infoPosition" :opened="infoOpened" @closeclick="infoOpened=false">
        {{infoContent}}
      </gmap-info-window>

      <gmap-marker v-for="(item, key) in coordinates" :key="key" :position="getPosition(item)" :clickable="true" @click="toggleInfo(item, key)" />

    </gmap-map>
  </div>

</body>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.0/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="vue-google-maps.js"></script>

<script>
var jsondata = {
   0: {
        full_name: 'Erich  Kunze',
        lat: '20.31',
        lng: '83.89'
      },
      1: {
        full_name: 'Delmer Olson',
        lat: '20.32',
        lng: '83.89'
      }
}

 $(function () {
 testdata();


;//= testdata();
Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, {
  load: {
    key: 'AIzaSyBzlLYISGjL_ovJwAehh6ydhB56fCCpPQw'
  },
});

new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  data: {
    startLocation: {
      lat: 20.3157,
      lng: 83.8854
    },
    coordinates: jsondata,
    <!-- { -->
      <!-- 0: { -->
        <!-- full_name: 'Erich  Kunze', -->
        <!-- lat: '20.31', -->
        <!-- lng: '83.89' -->
      <!-- }, -->
      <!-- 1: { -->
        <!-- full_name: 'Delmer Olson', -->
        <!-- lat: '20.32', -->
        <!-- lng: '83.89' -->
      <!-- } -->
    <!-- }, -->
    infoPosition: null,
    infoContent: null,
    infoOpened: false,
    infoCurrentKey: null,
    infoOptions: {
      pixelOffset: {
        width: 0,
        height: -35
      }
    },
  },
  methods: {
    getPosition: function(marker) {
      return {
        lat: parseFloat(marker.lat),
        lng: parseFloat(marker.lng)
      }
    },
    toggleInfo: function(marker, key) {
      this.infoPosition = this.getPosition(marker);
      this.infoContent = marker.full_name;
      if (this.infoCurrentKey == key) {
        this.infoOpened = !this.infoOpened;
      } else {
        this.infoOpened = true;
        this.infoCurrentKey = key;
      }
    }
  }
});

});
function testdata(){
alert('chk');
jsondata[2] = {
full_name : 'chk',
lat:20.33,
lng:83.89
}
console.log(jsondata);
}


</script>

</html>
```

It should plot all the markers two static and one dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with the code, Now the same code is working fine, it shows all the markers.It is working like a charm.

Thanks